# Using CodeDom to save a class to the solution

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, codedom

Is it possible? I have good source code, and I have instantiated an object from the dynamically generated source code, but I need to place this class into my solution.

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter whether or not this tool can do this. I have decided that it is too easy to do this with a couple lines of code. No need in rummaging through codedom's docs.

private static void CreateClass(string source, string fileName)
        {
            var folderName = @"";
            var pathString = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

            File.WriteAllLines(pathString, new string[] { source });
        }

Comment: Comments are occasionally temporary. It would be worthwhile to answer your own question with this, and accept it.